# task contains actions OR action contains tasks?

Tags: generic-noun-phrases

**Does a task contain actions to solve the task?**
*or*
**Does an action contain tasks to solve the action?**

I am a programmer and would like to get the names for my class structure as much intuitive readable as possible. Unfortunately I am not a native English speaker so I cannot intuitivly decide how tasks and actions would be intuitivly hierarchicaly connected by a native English speaker.

Note on the given *tag*:
In German we would call this connection between the nouns "Oberbegriff" which is translated to "generic term". Unfortunately I cannot tag this question with the tag "generic-term". Because I cannot create a new tag (lack of reputation), I just give it the nearest possible tag which is "generic-noun-phrases", which might not be quite appropriate.

If something is unclear or if the question cannot be answered without getting into furious discussions, because the usage would be opinion based, please leave a comment stating your opinion on the issue ;)

Comment: How are you using the words *task* and *action*? That is, in your context, what do those words refer to?

Comment: @Lawrence I am programming a point and click programming interface. That means you can "write" code by dragging and dropping code snippets. Currently I am using the word "task" where I would use a function in cpp and I use the word "action" where I would write something like a statement. So a task currently is a list of actions which are executed sequentially. The question is: Should an action rather be a list of tasks instead?

Comment: It sounds like you've answered the question already :) . One task ('function') can contain multiple actions ('statements'), so *tasks* contain *actions* in the given context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on how you are defining **task** and **action** which may be different in German, but usually

> a task - *something which needs to be done*

will usually have

> actions - *steps to achieve success*

For example, in a *To Do List*

> task: Grocery shopping
>
> > action: buy bread
> >      action: buy butter
> >      action: buy milk